# invoke MainActivity after splashscreen

Tags: java, android, main-activity

Calling the `MainActivity.java` after SplashScreen?

The code compiles correctly , but does not invoke the Main after the Splash in any way , it simply closes .

In `AndroidManifest.xml` calling SplashScreen and not MainActivity , make a difference?

**Manifest:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.stark.hello_world">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".Splashscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Splashscreen:**

```
package com.example.stark.hello_world;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * Created by Stark on 22/06/2016.
 */
public class Splashscreen extends Activity {

    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Thread splashTread;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
        StartAnimations();
    }
    private void StartAnimations() {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
        anim.reset();
        LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
        l.clearAnimation();
        l.startAnimation(anim);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
        iv.clearAnimation();
        iv.startAnimation(anim);

        splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    // Splash screen pause time
                    while (waited < 3500) {
                        sleep(100);
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    Splashscreen.this.finish();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                } finally {
                    Splashscreen.this.finish();
                }

            }
        };
        splashTread.start();

    }

}
```

**Main:**

```
 package com.example.stark.hello_world;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are finishing Splashscreen, but not starting MainActivity. Add startActivity(intent) like that;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent); // Add this
Splashscreen.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared MainActivity in AndroidManifest file. Once you add it there and it will work.

Comment: It includes other activity and yet splashscreen after the application is closed :( I will update the code here

Comment: In your SplashScreen, you haven't called startActivity method. Can you check that. Also, <i>Splashscreen.this.finish();</i> this line is written in both try and finally. if it is called in try then it will throw exception in finally. You can do the fixes. If it still doesn't work, then post the logcat response. That will give better idea about cause.